# Why do I get duplicate tags when serializing an enum with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I have this code:

```
let vid = VideoLayer::VideoConcatLayer(VideoConcatLayer {
    list: vec![VideoLayer::VideoAssetLayer(VideoAssetLayer {
        asset: T3Val::Ready(
            Ready {
                val: "hello".to_string()
            })
        })]
    });
```

Basically `VideoLayer` and `T3Val` are enums and `VideoConcatLayer`, `VideoAssetLayer`, and `Ready` are structs. The problem is that when I try to serialize it with serde, the "type" field is duplicated and it throws an error.

The serialized result is here:

```json
{"type":"VideoConcatLayer","type":"VideoConcatLayer","list":[{"type":"VideoAssetLayer","type":"VideoAssetLayer","asset":{"type":"Ready","type":"Ready","val":"hello"}}]}
```

Comment: It's really strange that Serde would do that. Is this a derived serializer, or a custom one?

Comment: To fix the weirdness with the `Ready` you need a function you can call like `Ready::new(...)`.

Comment: @tadman its a derived serializer

Comment: Please provide all the relevant enums and structs including the derive code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you won't share the code to reproduce the problem, I had to guess:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
enum VideoLayer {
    VideoConcatLayer(VideoConcatLayer),
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
struct VideoConcatLayer {
    list: Vec<…>,
}
```

Delete the `#[serde(tag = "type")]` from the structs, only put it onto enums, and your problem will go away.

And for future questions, please always share the full code necessary to reproduce your problem, maybe with a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02b822ff73447cc57674e13bd9c22816) link or including a list of dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I removed serdes from structs! In the future I will remember to attach the full code